# Transfer existing ERC-20 to BSC

Tags: erc-20

We have an existing running ERC-20 token on main net whith around 200 holders . We would like to move to Binance smart chain or TRON blockcchain as it offers high throuhput and lower tx fees. How should I approach to move my existing ERC20 to another chain especially balances

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use a bridge available on zapper to transfer your assets to polygon and then use polygon-bsc bridge to transfer to bsc since there is no direct eth-bsc bridge I think

Answer (score 0):

or you can just mint these tokens where ether ones are burned.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/56359)

Comment: @FlorianCastelain really?